# CSS: Make new line go above, not below

Tags: css, css-float

I have a `div` that has some floated children. When the `div`'s width becomes full, it continues to a new line, **below** the first line (which is the regular, expected behavior). [JSFiddle to show what I am talking about](http://jsfiddle.net/e7qde/).

I want it continue onto a new line **above** the first line instead following the flow. Is this possible with just **CSS**? How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** Here is a new link with [what it does and what I want it to do](http://jsfiddle.net/Ap2zK/)

**EDIT2:** [Here is an example with more elements](http://jsfiddle.net/YnKzL/)

Comment: So in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/e7qde/3/) you want `3 newline 1 2` ?

Comment: [Did i get this right?](http://jsfiddle.net/e7qde/6/) Just add `clear: both;` to the children.

Comment: Correct. To be honest, the best situation would really be 1 newline 2 3, but I can change what element is what later so. I figure for now 3 newline 1 2 is easier.

Comment: It's not easier, just ask about the thing you actually want to do. Please provide at least one example like I have, it's difficult to understand your question.

Comment: are these divs getting add dynamically?

Comment: Yes, they are getting added dynamically.

Comment: I am adding a JSFiddle to show what I want (the correct result)

Comment: Can you update the example to include more children? *Edit:* Or will it always contain max 3 children?

Comment: It can have more, I'm making an example now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: both;` to the child elements. That will force each child to it's own line.

http://jsfiddle.net/e7qde/6/

**Update:**

http://jsfiddle.net/e7qde/12/

Comment: I would still like to have all of the elements that can be inline, inline. Just any overflow should go above, not below.

Comment: Not sure i understand. So if you have a list of elements like `1 2 3 4 5", you want it to go like `5 - 4 3 - 2 1` ("-" being a linebreak)?

Comment: I just added a link to a new JSFiddle. This is what I want it to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Ap2zK/

Comment: Perfect, I have never seen `nth-child()`, works great. Thank you!

Comment: As was pointed out for my answer (which I removed because of this bug) this doesn't appear properly when you have 2 items

Comment: How is it supposed to look when you only have two? Should they float next to each other?

Comment: Change `clear: both;` to `clear: right;` and that should fix the problem (as noted by Andrew Morris' comment).

Answer (score 1):

If it is only ever going to be a separation between 1 and 2 (assuming more than 1 are added as you said it is dynamic) you could add an `nth-child` to your second `.child` item like this:

```
.child:nth-child(2) {
    clear:left;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YnKzL/1/)

Comment: The content is dynamic.  The OP's desired behavior is only for an odd number of elements.  When there's an even number, it looks wrong.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'd tested 1, 3 and above but forgotten about 2

Answer (score 1):

You're needing the `nth-last-child` selector:

http://jsfiddle.net/e7qde/16/

```
.child:nth-last-child(even) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Note that this isn't available in IE8 or older.